# How to show Application Launcher Dialog when do tap on button

Tags: android

I am getting app launcher dialog when i do tap on `Home` button with `two options` to set as home app - first, `default` phone app and second `mine app`, using this:

**Activity:**

```
public class DefaultLaunchActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_launcher);
    }   
}
```

**manifest.xml**

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.def.launc.DefaultLaunchActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>         
    </activity>
```

But what, if i have to show `Application Launcher Dialog` whenever user do tap on button

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // what to put here to show app launcher dialog         
            }
        });
```

Comment: the code code seems fine..u dont get icon when tap on home button?

Comment: @mtetno hello you mean app launcher icon when installed ? already there: android:launchMode="singleTask"

Comment: whenu install and tap on home , u didnt get u app option?

Comment: whenever i do tap on Home button, it ask me to select default launch app ! I just want to know how can i show same app launcher dialog when user do tap on button

Comment: ok u can go for action i mean there will be 2 option say :android home option--> where u just need to start intent as home and other apps u need to secific pacakage as start activity as secifiting custom action

Comment: Lets Disccuss on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34961/m-t-e-t-n-o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to customize some thing like below :

> **First : on click of button define this :**

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.mtetno.MYACTION"); 
startActivity(intent);
```

> **Second define this in manifest :**

```
<activity 
android:name=".AndroidHomeActivity" > 
<intent-filter> 
<action android:name="com.mtetno.MYACTION" / 
</intent-filter> 
</activity> 


<activity 
android:name=".MyActivity" > 
<intent-filter> 
<action android:name="com.mtetno.MYACTION" /> 
</intent-filter> 
</activity>
```

> **Write AndroidHomeActivity activity as :**

```
public class AndroidHomeActivity extends Activity { 
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME); 
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
startActivity(startMain); 

} 
}
```